# Why is my account still locked if I try to send a transaction?

Tags: accounts, json-rpc, nethereum

I unlocked my account and get result true but if I try to send:

```
var transactionHash = await contractname.SendTransactionAsync(contractAddress, new HexBigInteger(calculatedGas.HexValue), new HexBigInteger(2), inputA);
```

I only get that my account is locked:

> Nethereum.JsonRpc.Client.RpcResponseException: account is locked

Has someone an idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Not enough rep to comment.)

Need more information:

- client name and version ([Nethereum](https://github.com/Nethereum/Nethereum)?..);
- command used to unlock account (i.e. are you sure it's unlocked?).

In `geth`, specifying `{from: eth.accounts[42]}` could help, possibly there is something similar for Nethereum.

---

[Nethereum docs](https://nethereum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts/calling-transactions-events/#the-multiply-transaction) shows using `SendTransactionAsync()` with the first argument being the `senderAddress`. Is that what you have in `contractAddress`?..

Mind you, I know zero .Net.

Comment: Oh, I really mixed up the variables. Thx! Sometimes a solution can be so easy.